# LaTeX vertical daily schedule

Tags: diagrams

How can I make the following daily schedule in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Just a pointer: check TikZ calendars library section of the TikZ manual for the clues.

Comment: *I see you there, Ben.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do this is to:

- use a `tablular` to create the vertical numerical data,
- use [`collcell`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell) to apply a `\tikzmark` to each row of the table,
- use `tikz` to insert the brace and text based on row numbers.

[image]

### Notes:

- The data can be be allowed to auto wrap, or manually wrapped as in the brown text.
- You can change the alignment of the text via the `align=` options as shown in the blue, orange, and violet text.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\NewRowData}{r}<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcounter{RowCount}
\newcommand*{\NewRowData}[1]{%
        \stepcounter{RowCount}%
        \tikzmark{Left Mark of Row \arabic{RowCount}}%
            \makebox[1.0em]{#1}%
        \tikzmark{Right Mark of Row \arabic{RowCount}}%
}%


\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\LeftTextWidth}{6.0cm}
\newcommand*{\RightTextWidth}{6.0cm}
\newcommand\LeftBrace[4][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline]
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=6pt, amplitude=1.0ex, mirror}, ultra thick, #1] 
    ([yshift=3pt]Left Mark of #2.north east) 
    -- node[xshift=-10pt, align=left, text width=\LeftTextWidth, anchor=east, #1] 
            {#4} 
    ([yshift=3pt]Left Mark of #3.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}    
}

\newcommand\RightBrace[4][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline]
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=6pt, amplitude=1.0ex}, ultra thick, #1] 
    ([xshift=2pt, yshift=3pt]Left Mark of #2.north east) 
    -- node[xshift=10pt, align=left, text width=\LeftTextWidth, anchor=west, #1] 
            {#4} 
    ([xshift=2pt, yshift=3pt]Left Mark of #3.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}    
}


\begin{document}

{\centering%
\begin{tabular}{R}
5 \\
6 \\
  \\
7 \\
  \\
8 \\
9 \\
10 \\
11 \\
12 \\
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6 \\
7 \\
8 \\
9 \\
10 \\
11 \\
12 \\
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
\end{tabular}
\par}

\LeftBrace[red]{Row 1}{Row 5}{%
    Rise, wash, and address \emph{Powerful Goodness! Contrive day's business},
    and take the resolution of the day;%
}
\RightBrace[brown]{Row 1}{Row 5}{%
    The Morning. \\
    Question: What good shall I do \\
    this day?%
}
\RightBrace[magenta]{Row 6}{Row 9}{Work.}
\RightBrace[violet]{Row 10}{Row 11}{Read, or overlook my accounts, and dine.}
\LeftBrace[blue, align=center]{Row 10}{Row 11}{NOON.}
\RightBrace[olive]{Row 12}{Row 15}{Work.}
\LeftBrace[orange, align=center]{Row 16}{Row 19}{%
    Evening \\
    \emph{Question}: What good have I done \\
    today?%
}
\RightBrace[purple]{Row 16}{Row 19}{%
    Put things in their places. Supper.
    Music or diversion, or conversation/
    Examination of the day.
}
\LeftBrace[violet, align=center]{Row 20}{Row 26}{NIGHT.}
\RightBrace[red]{Row 20}{Row 26}{Sleep.}

\end{document}
```