# How to construct a synoptic table?

Tags: tables, diagrams

I need to construct a synoptic table as below, and to insert it in a LateX document. What kind of tool has to be used to do it ? If anyone has an example, I'm very interested !

Thanks for your help !

[image]

I propose here all the texts in order to send me an example :

```
Famille Bach & Copiste & Prélude & Fugue
\textit{J.S.} \newthought{Bach} \textit{naît à Eisenach} 
\textit{J.S.} \newthought{Bach}, \textit{élève à Lünebourg}
\textit{J.S.} \newthought{Bach}, \textit{organiste à  Arnstadt}
\textit{J.S.} \newthought{Bach}, \textit{organiste à Mühlausen}
\textit{J.S.} \newthought{Bach}, \textit{organiste et Konzertmeister à Weimar}
\textit{J.S.} \newthought{Bach}, \textit{Kapellmeister à C \oe then}
\textit{J.S.} \newthought{Bach}, \textit{Cantor à Leipzig} & Johannes Nicolaus \newthought{Mempell} (1713-1747)
 & Lorenz \newthought{Sichart} (1694-1771)
 & Johannes Nicolaus \newthought{Mempell} (1713-1747)

 \textit{J.S.} \newthought{Bach} \textit{meurt à Leipzig} & Leonhard \newthought{Scholz} (1720-1798)
& David Traugott \newthought{Nicolai} (1733-1799)
& Johannes \newthought{Ringk} (1717-1778)
& Inconnu (prov. : Jacob Heinrich \newthought{Westphal})
& \newthought{Palestrina II} ; Anon. V 19 (Kobayashi)
& Christian Friedrich \newthought{Schwencke} (1767-1822)

\textit{W.F.} \newthought{Bach} \textit{meurt à Berlin}
\textit{C.P.E.} \newthought{Bach} \textit{meurt à Hambourg}
& Johann Friedrich \newthought{Doles} (1715-1797) & en \textit{Ut} Maj.
& Inconnu (prov. : Jacob Heinrich \newthought{Westphal})

\textit{Première biographie de J.S.} \newthought{Bach}, \textit{meurt à Hambourg}

& Johann Andreas \newthought{Dröbs} (1784-1725)
& Friedrich August \newthought{Grasnick} (1798-1877)
& Inconnu (corr. : F. \newthought{Mendelssohn-Bartholdy}
& \newthought{Krüger} ; Anon. V 1 (Kobayashi)
& prov. : provenance
& corr. : corrections
```

Comment: It is very easy to construct something like this, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210862 (note that nowadays there is the `tikzmark` library available which makes things even simpler). It is just cumbersome to punch in these texts from the screen shot.

Comment: I try to answer your request... I am unable to understand how to construct this synoptic table.

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow The construction of this Table was an opportunity to learn TikZ usage. But I didn't know the procedures presented in your link. I will look. Thanks !